# EF4 CTP5: DbContext inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5, ef-code-first

I have a hierarchical `DbContext` structure, where I would like a specialized `DbContext` with its own `DbSets` to inherit the `DbSets` of a `BaseDbContext`.

While accessing the underlying `ObjectContext` with *((`IObjectContextAdapter`)this).`ObjectContext`* it takes too long (several minutes) to receive the `ObjectContext`.

Is there an issue with `DbContext` in CT5, that getting an `ObjectContext` from derived `DbContext` is not performantly possible?

The structure is: `DbContext(EF4) -> myBaseDbContext -> mySpecializedDbContext`.

Does anyone have an idea of what´s going on in this scenario?
It´s just POCO (CF) with TPC and a little inheritance.

Comment: How big is your DbContext hierarchy? How many DbSets do you have in your hierarchy?

Comment: The amount of DbSets is around 20 plus 8 derived DbSets. Not so huge at all.

Comment: Haven't seen this problem yet. Why do you need to get `ObjectContext`?

Comment: thx for answering Ladislav
Well, i have to use ObjectContext because i would like to adjust the behaviour of dealing with ProxyCreation und LazyLoading. Added to that, i have some methods which need the "underlying" oc.
e.g. "dbctx.UnderlyingContext.DeleteObject(entity);"
The problem occurs each time i access the oc in any way...

Comment: Are you doing anything heavy in the ProxyCreation und LazyLoading? Can you remove one or the other and see if it affects loading times.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have performance issues with following and you don't have so many DbSets:

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
    {       
       //your DbSets<> and other

       public ObjectContext ObjectContext()
       {
          return (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
       }
    }
```